# What learning requires one to חזר-review?

Tags: torah-study, adult-learning

To my knowledge, chazara programs usually accompanies review of Tanach, Gemara, etc. Is one suppose to chazar a book like ['Garments of the Soul'](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/15667) or maybe the 'nugget' from an article read that week?

Comment: If you want to remember something you should review it, or do whatever else it takes to remember it. There are no formal rules for review.